# How to reference subclass from a static superclass method in Groovy

Tags: groovy

A simplified version of what I'm trying to do in Groovy:

```
class Animal {
    static def echo() {
        println this.name  // ie "class.name"
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
}

class Cat extends Animal {
}

Dog.echo()
Cat.echo()

// Output:
//  => Animal
//  => Animal
//
// What I want:
//  => Dog
//  => Cat
```

I think what I'm asking here is: when I call a static method on an object, and
the static method is defined in the object's superclass, is there a way to obtain
the actual type of the object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A static method is not defined in the object context, but in the class context. You might get confused by the presence of `this` in the Groovy static method. However, it's only a syntactic sugar that eventually replaces `this.name` with `Animal.class.name`.

If you compile the `Animal` class from your example with a static compilation enabled, you will see that it compiles to the following Java equivalent (result after decompiling the *.class* file):

```java
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

import groovy.lang.GroovyObject;
import groovy.lang.MetaClass;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods;

public class Animal implements GroovyObject {
    public Animal() {
        MetaClass var1 = this.$getStaticMetaClass();
        this.metaClass = var1;
    }

    public static Object echo() {
        DefaultGroovyMethods.println(Animal.class, Animal.class.getName());
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can see that the following line in the `echo` method:

```
DefaultGroovyMethods.println(Animal.class, Animal.class.getName());
```

operates directly on the `Animal` class name. So from the `echo` method perspective, it doesn't matter how many classes extend it. As long as those classes invoke `echo` method defined in the `Animal` class, you will always see `Animal` printed as a result.

And there is even more than that. If you use the following compiler configuration script:

*config.groovy*

```
withConfig(configuration) {
    ast(groovy.transform.CompileStatic)
    ast(groovy.transform.TypeChecked)
}
```

and then compile the script (let's call it *script.groovy*) using this configuration option with the following command:

```sh
groovyc --configscript=config.groovy script.groovy
```

then you will see something like this after decompiling the *.class* file:

```java
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

import groovy.lang.Binding;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper;

public class script extends groovy.lang.Script {
    public script() {
    }

    public script(Binding context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        InvokerHelper.runScript(script.class, args);
    }

    public Object run() {
        Animal.echo();
        return Animal.echo();
    }
}
```

You can see that even though you have invoked `Dog.echo()` and `Cat.echo()` in your Groovy script, the compiler replaced these calls with the double `Animal.echo()` invocation. It happened because calling this static method on any other subclass does not make any difference.

### Possible solution: applying double dispatch

There is one way to get the expected output - override `echo` static method in `Dog` and `Cat` class. I can assume that your real method may do something more than the exemplary `echo` method you have shown above, so you might need to call the super `echo` method from a parent class. But... there are two problems: (1) you can't use `super.echo()` in the static context, and (2) it doesn't solve the problem, because parent method still operates in the `Animal` class context.'

To solve this kind of issue you might want to mimic a technique called [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch). In short - when we don't have information about the caller in the method that was called, let's allow the caller to pass this information with the method call. Consider the following example:

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
class Animal {
    // This is a replacement for the previous echo() method - this one knows the animal type from a parameter
    protected static void echo(Class<? extends Animal> clazz) {
        println clazz.name
    }

    static void echo() {
        echo(Animal)
    }
}

@CompileStatic
class Dog extends Animal {
    static void echo() {
        echo(Dog)
    }
}

@CompileStatic
class Cat extends Animal {
    static void echo() {
        echo(Cat)
    }
}

Animal.echo()
Dog.echo()
Cat.echo()
```

This may sound like a boilerplate solution - it requires implementing `echo` method in each subclass. However, it encapsulates the `echo` logic in the method that requires `Class<? extends Animal>` parameter, so we can let every subclass to introduce their concrete subtype. Of course, this is not a perfect solution. It requires implementing `echo` method in each subclass, but there is no other alternative way. Another problem is that it doesn't stop you from calling `Dog.echo(Animal)` which will cause the same effect as calling `Animal.echo()`. This double dispatch like approach is more like introducing a shorthand version of `echo` method which uses the common static `echo` method implementation for simplicity.

I don't know if this kind of approach solves your problem, but maybe it will help you find a final solution.

Comment: Very informative breakdown, and yes, the suggested pattern (put the bulk of the logic in the superclass and implement small wrappers in each subclass) will work fine.  I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing a more elegant "groovy-er" approach - your answer puts that idea to rest.